# how flask match list or return 404

Tags: python, flask, url

I am newbee to Flask from perl.

Now as follows, I want to match by the below route only for url list `[/list/user, list/course, list/teacher, ...]`, if request URL such as `"list/fxxk"` will get 404. How to achieve this in a smart way.

Thanks to anyone if any help.

```
@app.route('/list/<object>')
def list_object(object):
    # list all the object from DB
    return object
```

I think I can do a match inside the function. I want to know if there is any elegant to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flasks [any](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/routing/#werkzeug.routing.AnyConverter) converter:

```
@app.route('/list/<any(user, course, teacher):object>')
def list_object(object):
    # list all the object from DB
    return object
```